# Firebase Datasnapshot for getChildrenCount sets to zero

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Have a problem when getting the children count for my firebase database reference.

I am using a

```
private long childs;
```

this variable gets set in onCreate like this:

```
    ref_1 = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.com/traning/crossfit/level"+condition);
    ref_1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            childs = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

If i debug this code at the dataSnapshot it have counted the children and its correct, but when using this global variable childs on other places in the file there is somehow set to zero.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't get values out of ondatachange method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456650/cant-get-values-out-of-ondatachange-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `onDataChange()` method is called asynchronous. You cannot simply make `childs` variable global and use it anywhere you want in your class. This is happening because `onDataChange()` method is called even before you are getting the data from the database. For a better understanding, please see my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774).

For a quick fix, just use the value of your `childs` variable, only inside the `onDataChange()` method.

Comment: Thanks. This solved it to setup my view inside the onDataChange(), great, thanks.