# How to count children in Firebase Database (Android)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to count all the children that are in my Firebase database.

This is the Firebase structure:

`Level 1
 - CHILD1
 - - subchild1
 - - subchild2
 - CHILD2
 - - subchild 1`

How can I count the CHILDs from level 1? 
(In this example it would need to return 2...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference();

ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    Log.e(dataSnapshot.getKey(),dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");
}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

}

@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

}

@Override
public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Query` the first level and then in your SnapShot, use : [`getChildrenCount()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getChildrenCount()).

So the `query` will be something like this:

```
myRef.child("level1").child("subchild1"). // Your listener after
```

Check [this link](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot&method=getChildrenCount).

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029871/firebase-datasnapshot-for-getchildrencount-sets-to-zero).

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabaseRef.child("level1").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   long count= dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

                }  
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you .

```
(int)dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()
```