# How can I get the value of an arraylist that is updated inside an addValueEventListener?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show a `listview` from the `ArrayList` I am getting by the query.
The `ArrayList pt in addValueEventListener` becomes `null` outside the addValueEventListener although the `ArrayList` is declared as a static property. 
Is there any way to get the values of the `ArrayList` outside this `eventlistener?`

```
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot!=null) {
            Log.e("TAG", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("uid").child("Name")));
            int i=0;
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String userName = snapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
                Pt.add(userName);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  dataSnapshot.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datasnapshot is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't get values out of ondatachange method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456650/cant-get-values-out-of-ondatachange-method)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
private List<String> stringList=new ArrayList<>(); // define as class level

query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if(dataSnapshot!=null) {
        Log.e("TAG", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("uid").child("Name")));
        int i=0;
        for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            String userName = snapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
            Pt.add(userName);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  dataSnapshot.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datasnapshot is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stringList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Pt` list will always be `empty` outside the `onDataChange()` due the asynchronous behavior of this method. This means that by the time you are trying to use the `Pt` list outside this method, the data hasn't finished loading yet from the database and that's why is not accessible.

A quick solve for this problem would be to use the `Pt` list only inside the `onDataChange()` method or if you want to use it outside, I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.